# How to execute scripts in root folder from Apache using php

Tags: php, python

I need to run a python script before which I need to activate a virtual env for the script to run and it is in root folder. This is the command to do that (without using source command)

```
exec(root/Envs/ate/bin/python /var/www/cgi-bin/TStool/box_upgrade.py).
```

how do I execute from apache. I get 126 error in php. I have given the actual path.

> 126 error means- "Command invoked cannot execute. A permission or command not executable problem.".

How do I do this. The actual path is in the root folder, I can't move it to outside of root.

```
<?php
  $op=exec('/root/Envs/ate/bin/python /var/www/cgi-bin/TStool     /box_upgrade.py',$output,$return);
  echo "Dir returned $return, and output:\n";
  var_dump($output);
  echo $return;  
  echo $op;
    ?>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is your web server running as root? If not, it probably can't access anything in the `/root/` directory.

Comment: No it is running as apache. But I also tried moving the entire Envs/ate/bin/python  folder to another folder and tried running the script but it  gave return code 1(general error). Not sure what is the error.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to run this as PHP script instead of as machine-bootstrapping bash script or the like? Needing to exec from PHP is generally incredibly insecure.

Comment: The same script runs from console. Now I get a return code 1 in php. which means incorrect function. The command I gave is $op=exec('/var/www/cgi-bin/ate-activate/Envs/ate/bin/python /var/www/cgi-bin/TStool/box_upgrade.py',$output,$return);i gave full 777 permissions on all the folders and scripts.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans_ I m creating an online tool, got my front end as html and backend as php from which I need to run python script to upgrade/downgrade a server.

Answer (score 1):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell (as root if requested), it solves the limitations of exec() and shell_exec(). Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd('/root/Envs/ate/bin/python /var/www/cgi-bin/TStool/box_upgrade.py');
//the return will be a string containing the return of the command
echo $return1;
```

In terms of security it is far better than running apache as root. But letting PHP anywhere near root is always tricky.

The project i built achieves a root bash shell in one of 2 ways:

1) You allow apache the right to sudo python.

OR

2) You pass root credentials to the object every time you need a shell with root setup.

Pick your poison. :) Read the documentation.